# It's possible to read the text using scanf?

Tags: c

I need to read the text using scanf, but what I know scanf is reading characters to the first space. I don't know that it's possible to read more words into the array by scanf and i have no any idea.

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct; `scanf` reads *according to the format string* you give it.
Nothing keeps you from using a format that reads past spaces, returns, or whatever else, for example `scanf("%50c",buffer);` will read 50 characters, no matter what they are; or `scanf("%[^|]", buffer);` will read everything up the first `|`. Read up on the definition of the scanf family.